# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have problems, i'm writing function to edit listings menu, when i try to update file image then i meet the error in getClientOriginalName()

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

```
 @foreach($edits as $key => $value)
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $key }}" name="key_edit[{{ $key }}]">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-6">                      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="field-4">Tên menu</label>
                    <span class="desc">vd "Technology"</span>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="field-4" name="menu_title[{{ $key }}]" placeholder="Vui lòng điền tên" class="form-control" 
                        value="{{ $value->menu_title }}">

                        <input type="hidden" id="field-4" name="id_menu[{{ $key }}]" placeholder="Vui lòng điền tên" class="form-control" 
                        value="{{ $value->menu_id }}">

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-10 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="formfield10">Icon menu</label>
                    <span class="desc">vd. "character.jpg"</span>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" multiple="{{ $key }}" class="form-control" id="formfield10" name="upload_icon[{{ $key }}]">

                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $value->icon }}" name="icon_hidden[{{ $key }}]">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="col-md-1 btn-iconic">
                <div style="height:33px"></div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple pull-right"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 btn-iconic">
                <div style="height:33px"></div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple"><i class="fa fa-close "></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    </form>
```

MenuController

```
public function edit(Request $request){
            $input= $request->all();
            $edit = DB::table('categorys')->get();

            if($request->hasFile('upload_icon')) {
                $file = $input['upload_icon'];
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path().'/images/menu', $name);

                $id= $request->input('id_menu');
                $name = $request->input('menu_title');
                $icon= $name;
                foreach ($edit as $key => $value) {
                    DB::table('categorys')->where('menu_id', $id)->update([
                        'menu_id'=> $id[$key],
                        'menu_title' => $name[$key], 
                        'icon' => $icon[$key]
                    ]);

                }

            }
            else{               

                $id= $request->input('id_menu');
                $name = $request->input('menu_title');
                $icon= $request->input('icon_hidden');

                $key =$request->input('key_edit');
                foreach ($edit as $key => $value) {
                    DB::table('categorys')->where('menu_id', $id)->update([
                        'menu_id'=> $id[$key],
                        'menu_title' => $name[$key], 
                        'icon' => $icon[$key]
                    ]);

                }

            }
            return View('admin.menu.edit')->with('edits',$edit);
        }
```

dd($input['upload_icon']);

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#161 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "life_icon_post.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -size: 344
    -error: 0
    path: "E:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "phpB451.tmp"
    basename: "phpB451.tmp"
    pathname: "E:\xampp\tmp\phpB451.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "E:\xampp\tmp\phpB451.tmp"
    aTime: 2016-05-20 10:40:16
    mTime: 2016-05-20 10:40:16
    cTime: 2016-05-20 10:40:16
    inode: 0
    size: 344
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "E:\xampp\tmp\phpB451.tmp"
  }
  1 => null
]
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, please show result of `dd($input['upload_icon']);`

Comment: i updated code `dd($input['upload_icon']);`  on the questions

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're trying to use method on collection. You should use `foreach()` to iterate over files, or if you have just one file, do something like this:

```
$name = $file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: thank you, i change code and move  `$name = $file[$key]->getClientOriginalName();`
then this show `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`

Comment: It seems you're trying `1` as key. Did you try `0`? `$input['upload_icon'][0]->getClientOriginalName();` should give you `life_icon_post.png`

Comment: i changed `$name = $file[0] ->getClientOriginalName();`
this show:

`The file "life_icon_post.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`